# Laravel retrieving data using relationships

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I have `one-to-one` relationship between `Post` and `Category`. Let me try to illustrate columns. `Post columns`:

```
| id | pr_name | pr_description | ..... | `category_id`
```

And here is `Category columns`

```
| id | name
```

So what am I trying to do is the following. Category is already defined by me and will have only names of Categories. I should retrieve the name of category in my `Blade.php` file using it's id like this: `$post->category->name`. But I get error: `Trying to get property of non-object`. Here are my models: **Model of Post**

```
class Post extends Model
{
  public function category()
  {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Like','id','category_id'); // 'id' is foreign key,
                                                           // 'category_id' is local key 
  }
}
```

**Model of Category**:

```
class Category extends Model
{
  public function post()
  {
      return $this->belongTo('App\Post');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you mixed up the parent and the child. This is a one-to-many relationship because a single category can have multiple posts. This is reflected by the table design: you have category id as a foreign key in the posts table.

Comment: I tried that relationship. But then how can I get name of the category using post. I means: `category->$post->name`

Comment: Why is the model for `category` called `Like`?

Comment: Woow, you are attentive )

Comment: That was my problem. Thank you and thanks to @Shadow for correcting the relationship type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `Like` to `category`. And relationship, where **Category** `hasOne('App\Post')` and **Post** model `belongsTo('App\Category')`